# Javascript ES6 Promises with map

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to wait inside map function until all datas are fetched and then continue. I tried with the 'bluebird' library and came out with this.

Is this even working right and is there even better way to achieve this?

```
let urls = ['https://static.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/65609/tulip-tulips-sharpness-game-flower-65609.jpeg'];

let test = [];

Promise.map(urls, function(url) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    return getThumb(url);
}).then(function() {
    console.log(test);
});

function getThumb(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
    test.push(url);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v80wmmsv/4/

Thanks :)

**Edit:**

This is the final outcome:

```
let urls = ['https://static.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/65609/tulip-tulips-sharpness-game-flower-65609.jpeg'];

Promise.map(urls, getThumb).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.length);
}).catch(e => console.error(e));

function getThumb(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
  });
};
```

Comment: Did you try it? Is there a problem you are seeing?

Comment: I cant figure how to console.log to be sure if it works correctly. I just push the function parameter to an array at the end of the xhr and then log the array when map is done. I'm not very good with these async things

Comment: @JackM.: *"I just push the function parameter to an array at the end of the xhr..."* To be clear, you push it at the *start* of the XHR, not when it finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about that code, which may or may not be issues depending on what you want:

- `test` will end up with the URLs in the order in which they were requested (which I'm fairly sure is the same as their order in the original array, looking at the [`Promise.map` documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)), not the order in which they were resolved (if you care)
- `test` will contain the URLs even if they failed to load, since you're pushing them in the mapping function
- You're resolving your individual promises with the text (well, image data) of the response, but not using that text anywhere
- You're using an unnecessary wrapper function, no need for the wrapper around `getThumb`:

  ```
  Promise.map(urls, getThumb).then(function() {
      console.log(test);
  });
  ```

And one definite issue:

- You're not handling failure: You need a `catch` (or a `then` with the second [failure] callback).

Other than the lack of error handling, if the above is what you want, that code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concurrently run all promises and do something when all of them are resolved, you can use es2015 `Promise.all()`:

```
let urls = ['https://static.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg', 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/65609/tulip-tulips-sharpness-game-flower-65609.jpeg'];

let test = [];

Promise.all(urls.map(getThumb)).then(function() {
    console.log(test);
});

function getThumb(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
    test.push(url);
  });
};
```

Comment: And? It can also be done with bluebird's `Promise.map`, just as concisely but with handling of promises in the input array (not utilized in the OP's code, granted), as shown in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a few chars less to type at the cost of another dependency?

Comment: I'm not advocating using Bluebird. The OP *is* using Bluebird, and the question isn't "How do I do this without Bluebird?" (And Bluebird does a **lot** more than just save you a few characters. I don't use it, but I understand why people do.)